# What determines how files are ordered when using ls without sort?

Tags: filesystems, ls, c

The order when using `ls` with `-U` flag is the same order that I get when using dirent.h library in C and display file names in a loop. When I display `d_off` member of the `dirent` struct the numbers appear to be in ascending order.

Is the `d_off` the reason for the files' order and if so what is it exactly? I saw it being described as file offset but I'm not sure what that means.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man 3 readdir`:

> **d_off** 
>    The  value returned in d_off is the same as would be returned by calling telldir(3) at the current position in the directory stream.  Be aware that despite its type and name, the d_off field is seldom any kind of directory offset on modern filesystems.  Applications should treat this field as an opaque value, making no assumptions about its contents; see also telldir(3).

In other words, `d_off` and the ordering *are the same thing*; it's the number of the directory entry as returned by the file system for that directory.

The ordering is hence defined by the file system itself - and that might be simple (say, in a FAT12 directory) or very complex (say, an overlayFS over some complex file system).